# How to set a variable that is saved on another file in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Okay, so I want to be able to set my variable "EQP1" to whatever "chareqp1.txt" has printed in it. I have this, but it doesn't work, when I echo the variable it is saved as the text "C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp1.txt".

```
set /a "EQP1=C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp1.txt"
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `set /p` instead of `set /a`

```bat
Set /P "EQP1="<"C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp1.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong parameter, it's `set /p` and you need redirection to read the first line from a file.

```
set /p "EQP1=" <"C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp1.txt"
```

If it's not the first line you'll have to parse the file with `for /f` and maybe `findstr`

Comment: LotPings, looks like I was only fractions of a minute quicker than you this time!